# openLDAP で sudo のポリシーを管理する手順が分からない

Tags: linux, ldap

LDAPサーバの設定でsudoできるコマンドを制御したいのですが、手順がわかりません。
ブログ記事等をみたのですがsudoresのスキーマを読み込むことで、LDAPサーバがsudoの制御ができるようになるのでしょうか。

現状はLDAPサーバでユーザとグループを作成して、登録したユーザでクライアントに接続できるところまでは確認できています。

具体的な手順がわからず、何をすればLDAPサーバでsudoの管理ができるようになるのでしょうか。

openLDAPのバージョンは2.4.40です。

なお、「sudoersのスキーマを読み取らせる」手順は以下のサイトを参考に実行したのですが、記事が古く、現在ではslapd.confを変更するのは推奨されていないようです。

sudo用のスキーマを読み取らせるにはどのような手順で実行すれば読み取れますでしょうか。

[openLDAP 構築(18) - SUDOの管理(1)](http://arinux.jugem.jp/?eid=22)

Answer (score 2):

OSが書いていませんが、Linuxであると前提します。具体的な手順は、適当なLinuxで`man sudoers.ldap`と実行すると表示されます。もし、日本語のmanを入れていない場合は[こちら](https://manpages.opensuse.org/Tumbleweed/man-pages-ja/sudoers.ldap.5.ja.html)を見てください。

詳しくは上にmanページを見て欲しいのですが、既にLDAPサーバーが存在し、/etc/ldap.conf等が設定済みとした場合、だいたい次のような流れになります。

1. LDAPサーバーにsudoersのスキーマを読み取らせる。
2. LDAPでsudoers用のOU(通常はou=SUDOers)を作成する。
3. LDAPで上記のOU配下にsudoersのエントリーを作成する。(どのような設定がどのようなLDAPレコードになるかはmanページに説明あり)
4. /etc/ldap.conf(もしかしたら/etc/ldap/ldap.confかも)で`sudoers_base ou=SUDOers,dc=...(LDAPサーバーのベースDN)`を追加する。指定するOUは2.で作成したOU。
5. /etc/nsswitch.confに`sudores: ldap files`を追加する。/etc/sudoersを無視させたいなら`sudores: ldap`とする。(ここは`passwd: ladp filse`等と書いたのと同じ)

これで、sudoがLDAPを見に行くようになります。