# openLDAPでsudo用のスキーマを読み取らせる手順がわからない

Tags: linux, openldap, ldap

openLDAPでsuodのポリシーを管理しようとしています。

sudoersのスキーマを読み取らせる、の手順ですが以下サイトを参考に実行したのですが記事が古く、現在はslapd.confをいじる設定が推奨されていないようです。sudo用のスキーマを読み取らせるにはどのような手順で実行すれば読み取れますでしょうか・・
[openLDAP 構築(18) - SUDOの管理(1) | arinux](http://arinux.jugem.jp/?eid=22)

#### 試したこと

手順としてsudo用スキーマを登録する必要があり、sudo.ldifファイルを作成し、ldapaddを実行してもなにも反応がない(adding new entoryが返ってこない）のですが、記述にどこか誤りがあるのでしょうか。

sudo.ldif

```
#
# OpenLDAP schema file for Sudo
# Save as /etc/openldap/schema/sudo.schema
#

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.1
    NAME 'sudoUser'
    DESC 'User(s) who may  run sudo'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.2
    NAME 'sudoHost'
    DESC 'Host(s) who may run sudo'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.3
    NAME 'sudoCommand'
    DESC 'Command(s) to be executed by sudo'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.4
    NAME 'sudoRunAs'
    DESC 'User(s) impersonated by sudo (deprecated)'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.5
    NAME 'sudoOption'
    DESC 'Options(s) followed by sudo'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.6
    NAME 'sudoRunAsUser'
    DESC 'User(s) impersonated by sudo'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.7
    NAME 'sudoRunAsGroup'
    DESC 'Group(s) impersonated by sudo'
    EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.8
    NAME 'sudoNotBefore'
    DESC 'Start of time interval for which the entry is valid'
    EQUALITY generalizedTimeMatch
    ORDERING generalizedTimeOrderingMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.24 )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.9
    NAME 'sudoNotAfter'
    DESC 'End of time interval for which the entry is valid'
    EQUALITY generalizedTimeMatch
    ORDERING generalizedTimeOrderingMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.24 )

attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.10
    NAME 'sudoOrder'
    DESC 'an integer to order the sudoRole entries'
    EQUALITY integerMatch
    ORDERING integerOrderingMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 )

objectclass: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.2.1 NAME 'sudoRole' SUP top STRUCTURAL
    DESC 'Sudoer Entries'
    MUST ( cn )
    MAY ( sudoUser $ sudoHost $ sudoCommand $ sudoRunAs $ sudoRunAsUser $ sudoRunAsGroup $ sudoOption $ sudoOrder $ sudoNotBefore $ sudoNotAfter $
            description )
    )
```

---

全体の手順は下記投稿で確認し、sudo用のスキーマを追加する必要がありることがわかりました。しかし、その具体的手順がわからない(うまくいかない)ため、改めて質問しています。
[openLDAP で sudo のポリシーを管理する手順が分からない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/92976/openldap-%e3%81%a7-sudo-%e3%81%ae%e3%83%9d%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b7%e3%83%bc%e3%82%92%e7%ae%a1%e7%90%86%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%89%8b%e9%a0%86%e3%81%8c%e5%88%86%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

Comment: 前の質問から出てきた質問であっても「この質問を読んだだけで回答できる」ようにしましょう。そうしないと「前の質問も読む必要があるの？面倒くさいからこの質問を読むの止めよう」と思ってしまいます。結果的に回答しようとする人が少なくなって、回答が得られる可能性が低くなってしまいます。また、ファイルの中身はコードにするなどMarkdownを活用して整形すると読みやすくなって、回答されやすさが増します。これらを踏まえて質問を修正しましたので、確認してみてください。

Comment: 具体的なやり方は環境に依存する場合があります。OpenLDAPのバージョンのほか、OSとそのバージョン、OpenLDAPをどうやって入れたのか(パッケージ？ソースからコンパイル？)、そこからカスタマイズした内容(slapd.confをこうしたとか、このコマンドをうったとか)があると、環境にあった回答ができるかも知れません。その他、LDAPサーバーのセットアップしたときに参考にしたサイト等があれば、質問に追加してください。

Comment: 申し訳ございません・・・

Answer (score 0):

slapd.conf ではなく、OLC (slapd.d/) を使って設定しているのですね。
sudo.schema ファイルはそのままではインポートできません。
https://yasu-2.blogspot.com/2009/10/openldap-24_21.html を参考に、sudo.ldif ファイルに変換してからldapadd でインポートします。

また、sudo.schema の内容が古いようです。
Linux ディストリビューションが不明ですが、sudo パッケージに含まれていないでしょうか？
例えば、RHEL / CentOS 7.9 であれば /usr/share/doc/sudo-1.8.23/schema.OpenLDAP にあります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。OSはamazonlinux2です。
/usr/share/doc/sudo-1.8.23/schema.OpenLDAPにあるものをコピーし、ldapaddで登録できない（スキーマ登録できない）状態にになります。。

Comment: 失礼しました。schema は最新ですね。
登録できないとのことですが、ldif に変換しましたか？
ldapadd のエラーメッセージは？

Comment: ファイル拡張子をldifにしてldapaddを投入したら以下エラーが発生しました。
ldapadd: invalid format (line 1) entry: ""

同事象の記事を見つけまして(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025462/ldapadd-invalid-format-line-1-entry-when-adding-a-schema-on-systems-inclu)、同様の対処をした（コロンを入れた）のちに再度ldapaddをするも、今度は応答がない(ldapaaddをうっても反応がなく、エントリーされていない状況）です。。

Comment: 回答見ていますか？
.schema を .ldif に変換し、さらに .ldif を修正する必要があります。
.ldif は以下のようになります。

dn: cn=sudo,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: sudo
olcAttributeTypes: (以下略)